# Convergence of probability measures with respect to sequentially weak continuous functions

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis

Consider a separable Banach space $X$. The Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$ of $X$ is the same when taken with respect to the weak or strong topology. Hence, the space of probability measures over $X$ is the same with respect to the weak or the strong topology.

What differs is the topology of this space right? The weak convergence of a sequence of measures $\mu^n$ to $\mu$ is given by the convergence of integrals $$\int_X f(x) \mu^n(dx) \to \int_X f(x) \mu(dx)$$ for all weak-continuous functions or for all strong-continuous functions.

---

<s>Now, if $(\mu^n)$ is a tight family of probability measures on $X$ with respect to the weak topology, then $\mu^n$ is relatively compact (see [this notes by Kallianpur](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.lnms/1215451870)). Hence, there is a weakly convergent subsequence to a probability measure $\mu$, i.e. for all weak continuous f $${\int_X f(x) \mu^{n_k}(dx) \xrightarrow{k\to\infty} \int_X f(x) \mu(dx)}\,.$$</s>

---

Let $(\mu^n$) be a sequence of regular measures on $X$. If for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a metrizable compact subset $K_\varepsilon \subset X$ such that $$\inf_{n} \mu^n(K_\varepsilon) > 1 - \varepsilon\,,$$ then the sequence $(\mu^n)_n$ admits a weakly convergent subsequence $(\mu^{n_k})_k$ (see Theorem 8.6.7 in V.I. Bogachev's "Measure Theory V.2."). Hence, there is a prob. measure $\mu$ such that for any weak continuous map $f$ $$\int_X f(x) \mu^{n_k}(dx) \xrightarrow{k\to\infty} \int_X f(x) \mu(dx)\,.$$

My question is: In what cases can I show that for a sequentially continuous function $f$ we have $$\int_X f(x) \mu^{n_k}(dx) \xrightarrow{k\to\infty} \int_X f(x) \mu(dx) \,?$$

I was trying the following: For fixed $\varepsilon > 0$, find $B_R = \{x \in X | \|x\| \leq R\}$ such that $\mu^n(B_R) > 1 - \varepsilon$ for all $n > 0$.

I was trying to restrict $\mu^{n_k}$ to $B_R$ and show convergence there, but I run into problems when dealing with $\mu^{n_k}(B_R) \to \mu(B_R)$. With respect to the strong topology I can pick R slightly larger avoiding any atom in the boundary of $B_R$, i.e. there are countably many $R$ dense in $[0, \infty)$ such that $\mu(\partial B_R) = 0$, hence $B_R$ is a continuity set. This is not possible with respect to the weak topology because the boundary of $B_R$ is $B_R$ itself.

My intuition is that a sequence of measure can not capture the difference between sequential continuous and continuous functions, but I can put that down into rigorous math.

Comment: Is $X$ assumed separable?  I am not sure that the weak and strong topologies induce the same Borel $\sigma$-algebra otherwise.

Comment: Yes, $X$ is separable, I will add that. Thanks.

Comment: Also, given that $\mu^n$ is tight, how do you conclude it has a weakly convergent subsequence?  The usual version of Prohorov's theorem requires you are working on a separable metric space, but the weak topology isn't necessarily metrizable, not even on balls.  Unless you also want to assume $X$ is reflexive?

Comment: Hi, I'm basing this from the notes of Kallianpur in https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.lnms/1215451870 Theorem 2.2.1, the direction tight $\implies$ relatively weakly compact holds for Hausdorff spaces. The full Prokhorov requires Polish. Also, $X$ is reflexive as well.

Comment: Related to the remark by @NateEldredge: That a set of probability measures is relatively compact does not imply that the set is sequentially relatively compact. So there might be a sequence of probability measures that has no convergent subsequence but onlya convergent subnet, and a subnet of a sequence need not be representable by a subsequence. Maybe you can rule that out, but there should  be some argument then.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker thanks, I guess I should have been more careful in citing the result in Kallianpur notes. From the Theorem 2.2.1., we have that a tight sequence has a weakly convergent subsequence. The limit is explicitly constructed in the proof. 

Can I apply Eberlein–Šmulian theorem to say that this sequential relative compactness actually means relative compactness?

Comment: @JorgeE.Cardona I looked at the proof, and I don't really see how the subsequence is constructed. I don't think his proof works. Take a compact but not sequentially compact Hausdorff space. The standard example is $[01]^{[0,1]}$ with the product topology. Let $\langle x_n\rangle$ be a convergent sequence without a convergent subsequence. Then the family of Dirac measures $\{\delta_{x_n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is trivially tight, but not sequentially compact. The result as stated should hold at least for completely regular spaces though, this is Theorem 8.6.7. in Bogachev's book.

Comment: The Eberlein–Šmulian seems not to apply because "weak convergence of measures" is not "weak convergence" but "weak* convergence" from the functional analytic point of view. It is also stated in the Bogachev result mentioned that if the compact approximating sets used for tightness can be taken to be metrizable, then we actually get that every sequence has a converging subsequence. But weakly compact sets are generally not metrizable.

Comment: Kallianpur uses the compactness of the unit ball of the dual of $C(K)$ in the weak* topology, but to show that this unit ball is metrizable one typically uses the separability of $C(K)$. But $C(K)$ is only separable if $K$ is metrizable.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thank you, I will refer to Bogachev. Since $X$ is also separable I can use the second part of Theorem 8.6.7.

Let me check if I get the problem: From a sequence in the unit ball in $C(K_m)'$ we can only extract a subnet that may not be a sequence, right? To allow for a subsequence we need the unit ball in $C(K_m)'$ to be e.g. metrizable, this requires $C(K_m)$ to be separable. If $K_m$ is a compact metric space that works, right? I really appreciate your comment pointing this out with the right reference to Bogachev.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Do you mean: "Let $\langle x_n \rangle$ be a sequence without a convergent subsequence"?

Comment: @JorgeE.Cardona Yes, that is what I meant.